Polymer Brownian motion - fixed distance between particles
I would like to simulate the brownian motion of a polymer chain with Blender. I would like to model the polymer as a series of N segments of equal lengths L. So there would be N+1 vertices and each vertex moves with Brownian motion and has a fixed distance L from the adjacent ones.
I tried with particles systems, but I cannot find a way to fix the distance L between particles emitted from adjacent nodes.
